# Returning three ints together

Tags: java, swap

I am working on a simple program and I need to swap the tens digits of two numbers with conditions. If the tens digit of num1 is larger than the tens digit of num2, then return num1. If the tens digit of num1 is less than the tens digit of num2 then swap the tens digits and print num1 (with the swapped tens digit). Example : `987 123` returns 987 and `234 356` returns 254.

Here is my code so far:

```
public int swapForBigTensPlace (int num1, int num2) 
{
    int swap;
    int a = num1%10;
    int b = num1/10%10;
    int c = num1/100%10;
    int a1 = num2%10;
    int b1 = num2/10%10;
    int c1 = num2/100%10;
    if(b>b1)
        return num1;


    else if(b1 > b) 
       swap = supposed to be a, b1, and c next to each other;

    return swap;
}
```

I don't know how to make it so that it will return three ints next to each other, and not add them. Please show me how to do this. Thank you!

Comment: so the real question is not how to swap digits (title), but how to put 3 digits together

Comment: Yea. Sorry, my first goal was to swap the digits but in order to swap them, you need to put them together. I'll change that. Thanks!

Comment: You can't "return 3 ints".  You can return "an array of 3 ints" or "some object containing 3 ints".  The ```return``` statement returns one thing, whether it's an individual value, or some sort of parcel that wraps up 3 values into 1.

Comment: Why is it that the integers `a`, `b`, and `c` are the ones, tens and hundreds digits? (What I mean is "why is `c` the hundreds digit instead of `a`")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do want to add them.  You just need to undo the math you originally did for those numbers.  Like this:

```
swap = (a * 100) + (b1 * 10) + c
```

Comment: But that would swap a and c around so instead of 234 356 returning 254, it would return 452.

Comment: Based on the code you entered it seems like `a` is the hundreds digit, `b` is the tens digit, and `c` is the ones digit.  If that's not correct and `a` and `c` are swapped, just swap `a` and `c` in the code i provided

Comment: @Austin `a = num1 % 10` is not the hundreds (or was the code edited?) @Tristan shouldn't be to hard to change the order (swap `a` and `c` in the formula, or change the multipliers)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger is correct, c is the hundreds, and a is the ones digit, so the correct formula to return what you want is `swap = (c * 100) + (b * 10) + a`